# Alexa skill w/ Account Linking and gmail API .NET - Authentication

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, account, alexa-skills-kit

I have created an Alexa skill and enabled account linking. Setup my skills configuration to point to googles authorization and token servers, the skill successfully links. Then alexa sends POST Requests to my service that include the access token and state from Google. I use this to validate the token and what I want to do is use the token to access gmail api and begin calling actions.

However, the only examples online I can find include re-building the gmailservice by using the client secret and client id again. I figure since I have the access token already, why do I need to include the secret and ID again? How can i make gmail api calls with the access token I already have, or is this not possible? Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/gmail-dotnet-quickstart.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }

        // Create Gmail API service.
        var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

        // Define parameters of request.
        UsersResource.LabelsResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Labels.List("me");

        // List labels.
        IList<Label> labels= request.Execute().Labels;
        Console.WriteLine("Labels:");
        if (labels != null && labels.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var labelItem in labels)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", labelItem.Name);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No labels found.");
        }
        Console.Read();
```

I don't want to include the client_secret.json file because I already was authorized by google's oauth process in the alexa skill's account linking. Help ?

Comment: Hiya, I know its been a while, but this Github repository may be helpful.
https://github.com/beckyricha/alexa-gmail